# JAVA - read binary file with header (trying to transfer c# code)

Tags: java

I have some old C# code that does what I need, with the file type I'm working with, but I need to get it into Java. I've been reading up on binary I/O but I can't figure out how to deal with the header and I don't understand the C# code enough to know what it's doing

I would appreciate any assistance - mostly with understanding what the C# code means when it uses `br.readInt32()` and such and how to emulate that with Java which (as I understand it) reads the binary differently

I don't understand binary files very well (nor do I want to, this is a one off code piece), I just want to get the data out then I can work on the code that I understand better.

thanks

C# snippet:
[code]

```
    public void ConvertEVDtoCSV(string fileName)
    {
        string[] fileArray = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
        float minX = 0;
        float maxX = 0;

        try
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

            /*
                16 + n*80*6 = sizeof(header) where n is the 9th nibble of the file (beginning of the 5th byte)
            */

            //Reads "EVIS" 
            br.ReadBytes(4);
            //Reads numDataSets
            int numDataSets = br.ReadInt32();
            //Reads lngNumPlotSurfaces
            int lngNumPlotSurfaces = br.ReadInt32();
            //Reads headerEvisive length
            int headerEvisive = br.ReadInt32();
            //skip all six title and axes text lines.  
            int remainingHeader = (lngNumPlotSurfaces * 6 * 80) + headerEvisive;

            br.ReadBytes(remainingHeader);      //could also use seek(remainingHeader+16), but streams don't support seek?

            long dataSize = numDataSets * (2 + lngNumPlotSurfaces); //meb 6-8-2016: +2 for X and Y
            string[] dataForCSVFile = new string[dataSize];

            for (long cnt = 0; cnt < numDataSets; cnt++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 2 + lngNumPlotSurfaces; j++)    //+2 for X and Y
                    {
                    //don't read past the end of file
                    if (br.BaseStream.Position<br.BaseStream.Length) {
                    //This is where the data needs to be read in and converted from 32-bit single-precision floating point to strings for the csv file
                    float answerLittle = br.ReadSingle();
                    if (j == 0 && answerLittle > maxX)
                        maxX = answerLittle;
                    if (j == 0 && answerLittle < minX)
                        minX = answerLittle;
                    if (j > lngNumPlotSurfaces)
                        dataForCSVFile[cnt * (2 + lngNumPlotSurfaces) + j] = answerLittle.ToString() + "\r\n";
                    else
                        dataForCSVFile[cnt * (2 + lngNumPlotSurfaces) + j] = answerLittle.ToString() + ",";
                    }
                }
            }
            fs.Close();
            textBox_x_max.Text = (maxX).ToString("F2");
            textBox_x_min.Text = (minX).ToString("F2");
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(tempfile);      

            for (int i = 0; i < dataForCSVFile.Length; i++)
            {
                sw.Write(dataForCSVFile[i]);
            }
            sw.Close(); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { Console.WriteLine("Error reading data past eof."); }
    }
```

Comment: changed title.  i was given the code snippet from an old employee as "c++", i have no resource to know it's c#.

Answer (score -1):

From MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readint32(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

> Reads a 4-byte signed integer from the current stream and advances the current position of the stream by four bytes."

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readsingle(v=vs.110).aspx

> A 4-byte floating point value read from the current stream.

For reading the integer in Java, you will also have to pay attention to endianness. C# BinaryReader is small endian by default, while Java is big endian. So when reading integers you will have to read 4 bytes, swap their order and recombine them.

Comment: thanks for that, was just reading through those docs.  i've found some code snippets on endian reversal so hopefully i can figure this out.